# Algebraic data types containing class types in F#

Tags: f#

Algebraic data types are represented in F# by using Sum (Discriminated Unions) and product (tuples) types. I can then combine these elements as in algebra.

I can also define a tuple of two class types like this :

```
type MINT (i:int) =
    member x.i = i

type MINTtuple = MINT * MINT

let  v :MINTtuple= MINT(42), MINT(43)

(fst v).i |> printfn "%d" |> ignore
```

But I cannot seem to define a DU containing class types like this or any other syntax I could think of after looking at some [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233226.aspx) :

```
type MINTDU = 
    |Positive of MINT
    |Negative of MINT
let w = Positive MINT(45)
```

My **question** : if it is not possible, what are the fundamental reasons ? I am very happy with F# features as they are. I only want to better understand what are the tensions between functional types and class types. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need some brackets. Try this:

```
let createPositiveMint i =
    Positive (MINT i)
```

If you don't want a separate function as in your sample it would just be

```
let w = Positive (MINT 45)
```

Edited as per @kaefer suggestion.

Comment: You don't always need that many parentheses. Construction expressions are possible without them, it's when they're nested that the outer pair is required: `let w = Positive(MINT 45)`

Comment: @Kevin : Thanks. All those paren made me sick. Recovered.